# Check if a file exists in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a block if a directory exists in my jenkins workspace and the pipeline step ***"fileExists: Verify file exists"*** in workspace doesn't seem to work correctly.

I'm using Jenkins v 1.642 and Pipeline v 2.1. and trying to have a condition like

```java
if ( fileExists 'test1' ) {
  //Some block
}
```

What are the other alternatives I have within the pipeline?

Comment: Please describe the incorrect behavior you observe:

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You need to use brackets when using the [`fileExists`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) step in an `if` condition or assign the returned value to a variable

Using variable:

```java
def exists = fileExists 'file'

if (exists) {
    echo 'Yes'
} else {
    echo 'No'
}
```

Using brackets:

```java
if (fileExists('file')) {
    echo 'Yes'
} else {
    echo 'No'
}
```

Comment: def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("Report.txt")
which one is correct? def exists = fileExists reportPath OR def exists = fileExists 'reportPath'. 
I'm getting a message [Could not find content token (check your usage): fileExists] in both case.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this syntax (`fileExists` with brackets) -- "WorkflowScript: 90: Expected a step @ line 90, column 21", with a caret pointing at the `if`.

Comment: What about file name comparison? Does this method use case sensitive comparison when comparing file names? If yes, then how it is possible to compare in case insensitive manner?

Comment: For declarative Jenkinsfile you can use fileExists(file: 'src/test/java') (eg. for an when-expression for steps in a stage)

Comment: @MariusGedminas The if statement cannot be at top-level within a "step" in a pipeline. Enclose the if statement within a script tag to fix this. E.g, step { script { if (condition) { doSomething() } } }

Comment: If I use your code (in variable) it returns always 'false'. I had to declare it like this: `def exists = fileExists ("${mypath}/${myfile}")` perhaps it's because I use variables ${} inside.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that there is a difference when checking if file exists on a Jenkins master or agent (formerly slave). For example, consider this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53048193/1971003

Answer (score 17):

The keyword "return" must be used

```
stage('some stage') {
    when { expression { return fileExists ('myfile') } }
    steps {
           echo "file exists"
          }
    }
```

Comment: This worked fine at my side. I think this is a cleaner solution if one is writing pure Jenkins Pipeline DSL not using any 'script' parts. 
In my case I needed to test if a file does not exist so I did:
  when { not { expression { return fileExists ('myfile') } } }

Comment: not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843448/jenkins-pipeline-when-is-evaluating-to-false-though-file-exits