# Jenkins How to get the result of a bat command

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy

I have a problem: In my pipeline, I need to know if a certain file already exists. Here is my code :

```
if(...){
    bat 'if exist <insert file name here> (
             rem file exists
        ) else (
             rem file doesn't exist
        )'
}
```

I would like to know if I can get a return from that bat command so I could do something in my if(...) like : the return is true:do... or false:do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this directly in the pipeline script, you could use the code from the following question:

[Check if a file exists in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534781/check-if-a-file-exists-in-jenkins-pipeline)