# Jenkins Pipeline file exists if else

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

everybody,
I have a problem with a stage in a Declaritive pipeline in Jenkins. 
I'd like Jenkins to check if the directory /root/elp contains data with the name *.php If this is the case, jenkins should execute a command. If there is nothing in the folder, Jenkins should finish the job with success.

My Code that not function :

```
        stage('Test Stage') {
        steps {
            script {
                def folder = new File( '/root/elp/test.php' )
                    if( folder.exists() ) {
                        sh "LINUX SHELL COMMAND"
                    } else {
                        println "File doesn't exist" 
                    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below:-

```
def exists = fileExists '/root/elp/test.php'

if (exists) {
    sh "LINUX SHELL COMMAND"
} else {
    println "File doesn't exist"
}
```

And you can follow [check-if-a-file-exists-in-jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534781/check-if-a-file-exists-in-jenkins-pipeline)

And you can also use below:-

```
def exitCode = sh script: 'find -name "*.zip" | egrep .', returnStatus: true
boolean exists = exitCode == 0
```

Comment: I have one more question: How can I say that no matter what file exists. But which file extension I want to have all files named *.php.  my first try are : def exists = fileExists '/root/elp/*.php' but it not function

Comment: try with " * ", something like - def exists = fileExists '/root/elp/*.php'

Comment: That not work :(    def exists = fileExists '/root/elp/*.php'  I must say the name Otherwise, he won't do it.

Comment: yeah fileExists will not take wildcards, so better you install the optional Pipeline Utility Steps plugin, you can make use of the findFiles step (please refer - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-findfiles-code-find-files-in-the-workspace )

Comment: Would be the new code with pipeline utility :    def files = findFiles '/root/elp/*.php' ?

Answer (score 1):

The following example is when using [Jenkins declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-pipeline-fundamentals):

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        MY_FILE = fileExists '/tmp/myfile'
    }
    stages{
        stage('conditional if exists'){
            when { expression { MY_FILE == 'true' } }
            steps {
                echo "file exists"
            }
        }
        stage('conditional if not exists'){
            when { expression { MY_FILE == 'false' } }
            steps {
                echo "file does not exist"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively for [scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals) you may find this [bash syntax to check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash#638980) useful.