# How to fail jenkins job if source directory does not exist in file spec

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using Jenkins Artifactory Plugin to download files from Artifactory.I want to make jenkins job failed if source directory,value of pattern field in file spec,doesn't exist.Right now it says "No artifact found" but job doesn't fail.

Comment: IF you are using pipelines your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38539009/1289629

Comment: This functionality does exist, but you can use the "failNoOp" option, as described in the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin documentation, to fail the build if no files were downloaded using the file spec.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.I have done something different to resolve this.I wrote one batch script to check if file exist or not.