# Groovy "No candidates Found for method call file.exists()" error

Tags: groovy

Below is my groovy code snippet

```
def filePath = '/logs/result.txt'
def file = new File(filePath)
echo "${file.exists()}"
```

Output :

> result file.exists() = false

But the file /logs/result.txt is actually present.

Also,
In IntelliJ editor,
file.exists() is shown with dotted underline.

```
  When I hover mouse over the exists() method it says "No candidates Found for method call  file.exists()".
```

Comment: `false` means that file doesn't exist or path is incorrect. Replace `def file =` with `File file =` to remove intellij warning.

Comment: Echo? Are you running in Jenkins? If yes better to use native Jenkins file-steps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534781/check-if-a-file-exists-in-jenkins-pipeline